# How to create a dynamically sized form background with CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, background

I've been working on a project that involves essentially redoing an entire site, minus the layout, some of which I had to carry over, such as the Login page.

Right now, the login page consists of two boxes that are just static images. I'd like to replace both of them with one, dynamically sized background image.

One of the two current boxes contains this image as the background:

[image]

I'd like something extremely similar to this, even with the gradient if possible. I'd also like to keep the weird shadowing effect that's all around the edges.

I'm a developer, not a designer. Can anybody help me out here? CSS is far from my forte.

By request, here are the form contents:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This CSS would do great. I have taken care of all the browsers:-

```
#mainLogin {
  margin: 5px;
}

.align-left {
  float: left;
}

.align-right {
  float: right;
}

.login {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(1, 2, 2, 1);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(1, 2, 2, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #e1ffff 0%, #e1ffff 7%, #e1ffff 12%, #fdffff 12%, #e6f8fd 30%, #c8eefb 54%, #bee4f8 75%, #b1d8f5 100%);
 /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#e1ffff), color-stop(7%,#e1ffff), color-stop(12%,#e1ffff), color-stop(12%,#fdffff), color-stop(30%,#e6f8fd), color-stop(54%,#c8eefb), color-stop(75%,#bee4f8), color-stop(100%,#b1d8f5));
 /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #e1ffff 0%,#e1ffff 7%,#e1ffff 12%,#fdffff 12%,#e6f8fd 30%,#c8eefb 54%,#bee4f8 75%,#b1d8f5 100%);
 /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #e1ffff 0%,#e1ffff 7%,#e1ffff 12%,#fdffff 12%,#e6f8fd 30%,#c8eefb 54%,#bee4f8 75%,#b1d8f5 100%);
 /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #e1ffff 0%,#e1ffff 7%,#e1ffff 12%,#fdffff 12%,#e6f8fd 30%,#c8eefb 54%,#bee4f8 75%,#b1d8f5 100%);
 /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #e1ffff 0%,#e1ffff 7%,#e1ffff 12%,#fdffff 12%,#e6f8fd 30%,#c8eefb 54%,#bee4f8 75%,#b1d8f5 100%);
 /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e1ffff', endColorstr='#b1d8f5',GradientType=0 );
 /* IE6-8 */
  background: #e1ffff;
 /* Old browsers */;
}


/*CSS For Button*/

.myButton {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffe0b5;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffe0b5;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffe0b5;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #fbb450), color-stop(1, #f89306));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450 5%, #f89306 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450 5%, #f89306 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450 5%, #f89306 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450 5%, #f89306 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fbb450 5%, #f89306 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fbb450', endColorstr='#f89306',GradientType=0);
  background-color: #fbb450;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #c97e1c;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #8f7f24;
}

.myButton:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #f89306), color-stop(1, #fbb450));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f89306 5%, #fbb450 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f89306 5%, #fbb450 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f89306 5%, #fbb450 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f89306 5%, #fbb450 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f89306 5%, #fbb450 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f89306', endColorstr='#fbb450',GradientType=0);
  background-color: #f89306;
}

.myButton:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

and the HTML is as follows:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="login"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can have a look at JSBin too  http://jsbin.com/inegum/9/edit

Comment: @keyCrumbs if You want that you can actually use percentages to achieve it, so that the height and weight remain the same. Could you show a sample ... I can workout for you may be?

Comment: There is no need to specify the width and height at all; it will just behave like any other block and the background will stretch to the size.

Comment: All of them. The gradients are supposed to be identical, except for the prefixes. Some time in the future, the prefixes will not be necessary and you will need only one gradients property.

Comment: @keyCrumbs for time being if you are using Mordern Browser then too you have to use the prefixes. If you dont want to use them then only select the prefixes that are necessary for you for example.
Its mentioned clearly which one is for which browser. So select wisely. Since I build for all platform I use this. Another Quick Tip. Use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ for getting such gradients. Would be really helpful :)

Comment: @keyCrumbs Did you find this useful??

Answer (score 0):

Try an inset box-shadow like:

```
.background {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #555555;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #555555;
    box-shadow: inner 0 0 5px #555555;
}
```

You can use transparency as well like a rgba() if you don't have to support old IE.

Comment: Actually that last line is dumb now that I think about it.